# Error: Integrating terra components into Ionic3 app

Tags: typescript, webpack, ionic3, angular-components, webpack-style-loader

I am trying to integrate terra components(third party angular component) into ionic 3. We got the error as below.

[image]

To load the scss files we have added we have used the loader in webpack.config.js. The code for webpack.config.js is as follows

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ProvidePlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProvidePlugin');
const OccurrenceOrderPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/OccurrenceOrderPlugin');
const LoaderOptionsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/LoaderOptionsPlugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const helpers = require('./helpers');
const METADATA = {
baseUrl: './'
};
var path = require('path');
module.exports = function (options) {
//isProd = options.env === 'production';
return {
    entry: {
        'bootstrap': 'bootstrap-loader',
        'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
        'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
        'app': './src/main.ts'
    },
    output:{
      path: path.join(__dirname,'public/assets/'),
      publicPath:'assets/'
  },
    resolve: {
        descriptionFiles: ['package.json'],
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.css', '.scss', 'json', '.html']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: [
                    'awesome-typescript-loader',
                    'angular2-template-loader'
                ],
                exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html-loader',
                exclude: [helpers.root('src/index.html')]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'to-string-loader',
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
              test: /\.scss$/,
              loader: 'style!css!sass!resolve-url!sass?sourceMap&sourceComments'
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: 'json-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|svg)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?mimetype=application/font-woff'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff2)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?mimetype=application/font-woff2'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: "file-loader"
            },
            // Bootstrap 4
            {
                test: /bootstrap\/dist\/js\/umd\//,
                loader: 'imports-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [

        // Workaround for angular/angular#11580
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
            helpers.root('./src'), // location of your src
            {} // a map of your routes
        ),

        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills'],
            minChunks: Infinity
        }),

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html',
            inject: true,
            metadata: METADATA
        }),

        new OccurrenceOrderPlugin(true),

        new ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery",
            // Tether: "tether",
            // "window.Tether": "tether",
            Alert: "exports-loader?Alert!bootstrap/js/dist/alert",
            Button: "exports-loader?Button!bootstrap/js/dist/button",
            Carousel: "exports-loader?Carousel!bootstrap/js/dist/carousel",
            Collapse: "exports-loader?Collapse!bootstrap/js/dist/collapse",
            Dropdown: "exports-loader?Dropdown!bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown",
            Modal: "exports-loader?Modal!bootstrap/js/dist/modal",
            Popover: "exports-loader?Popover!bootstrap/js/dist/popover",
            Scrollspy: "exports-loader?Scrollspy!bootstrap/js/dist/scrollspy",
            Tab: "exports-loader?Tab!bootstrap/js/dist/tab",
            Tooltip: "exports-loader?Tooltip!bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip",
            Util: "exports-loader?Util!bootstrap/js/dist/util"
        }),

        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {from: 'src/app/assets', to: 'assets'},
            {from: 'node_modules/@plentymarkets/terra-components/app/assets/lang', to: 'assets/lang/terra-components/'}
        ]),

        new LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            debug: true,
            options: {
                context: __dirname,
                output: {path: './'},
                postcss: [autoprefixer],
                tslint: {
                    emitErrors: false,
                    failOnHint: false,
                    resourcePath: helpers.root('./src'),
                    formattersDirectory: "./node_modules/tslint-loader/formatters/"
                }
            }
        })
    ],
    node: {
        global: true,
        process: true,
        Buffer: false,
        crypto: 'empty',
        module: false,
        clearImmediate: false,
        setImmediate: false,
        clearTimeout: true,
        setTimeout: true
    }
}
};
```

Still I am getting the same error. As a new bee to webpack I am not able to understand what wrong I am really doing. What could be the error. Let us know if any details are required.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is with the loaders in your webpack.config.js.

Try replacing with your loaders with mine, that should work for you.

You can replace the whole code though.

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ionicWebpackFactory = require(process.env.IONIC_WEBPACK_FACTORY);

var ModuleConcatPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/ModuleConcatenationPlugin');
var PurifyPlugin = require('@angular-devkit/build-optimizer').PurifyPlugin;

var optimizedProdLoaders = [
  {
    test: /\.json$/,
    loader: 'json-loader'
  },
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: [
      {
        loader: process.env.IONIC_CACHE_LOADER
      },

      {
        loader: '@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/webpack-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: true
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    test: /\.ts$/,
    loader: [
      {
        loader: process.env.IONIC_CACHE_LOADER
      },

      {
        loader: '@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/webpack-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: true
        }
      },

      {
        loader: process.env.IONIC_WEBPACK_LOADER
      }
    ]
  }
];

function getProdLoaders() {
  if (process.env.IONIC_OPTIMIZE_JS === 'true') {
    return optimizedProdLoaders;
  }
  return devConfig.module.loaders;
}

var devConfig = {
  entry: process.env.IONIC_APP_ENTRY_POINT,
  output: {
    path: '{{BUILD}}',
    publicPath: 'build/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: ionicWebpackFactory.getSourceMapperFunction(),
  },
  devtool: process.env.IONIC_SOURCE_MAP_TYPE,

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json'],
    modules: [path.resolve('node_modules')]
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: process.env.IONIC_WEBPACK_LOADER
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ['to-string-loader','css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: [
          'to-string-loader',
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
          {
            loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
            options: {
              resources: 'node_modules/@plentymarkets/terra-components/app/assets/styles/_variables.scss'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    ionicWebpackFactory.getIonicEnvironmentPlugin(),
    ionicWebpackFactory.getCommonChunksPlugin()
  ],

  // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
  // Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  }
};

var prodConfig = {
  entry: process.env.IONIC_APP_ENTRY_POINT,
  output: {
    path: '{{BUILD}}',
    publicPath: 'build/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: ionicWebpackFactory.getSourceMapperFunction(),
  },
  devtool: process.env.IONIC_SOURCE_MAP_TYPE,

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json'],
    modules: [path.resolve('node_modules')]
  },

  module: {
    loaders: getProdLoaders()
  },

  plugins: [
    ionicWebpackFactory.getIonicEnvironmentPlugin(),
    ionicWebpackFactory.getCommonChunksPlugin(),
    new ModuleConcatPlugin(),
    new PurifyPlugin()
  ],

  // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
  // Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  }
};


module.exports = {
  dev: devConfig,
  prod: prodConfig
}
```

Comment: I was struggling with issue from so many days. At last it worked. You saved my day. Thanks for the answer.